# If $P(x) = (x^4+x^3-3x^2+4x-4)\cdot q(x) + (2x^3-5x^2+7x-3)$ find $P(2)$

Tags: polynomials

> If for the polynomial $P(x)$ is true that $$P(x) = (x^4+x^3-3x^2+4x-4)\cdot q(x) + (2x^3-5x^2+7x-3)$$ find $P(2)$

I assumed that the polynomial $(x^4+x^3-3x^2+4x-4)$ has $(x-2)$ as one of its factors, but it turns out that this is not true.

By the equation we got that $P(2)=16\cdot q(2) + 7$ but I don't know what I should do next.

Comment: Obviously there's nothing else you can do. Check the original statement.

Comment: The problem writer might have meant for that polynomial to be $x^4+x^3-3x^2\color{red}{-}4x-4$ or $x^4\color{red}{-}x^3-3x^2+4x-4$, in which case $x -2$ would be a factor of that polynomial.

Comment: The original statement is:
The remainder of the division of $P(x)$ with $(x^4+x^3-3x^2+4x-4)$ is $(2x^3-5x^2+7x-3)$. Find the remainder of the division $P(x):(x-2)$
Isn't it the same?

Answer (score 0):

I give you what I think is the only chance that your problem has a meaning.

There are many possibilities for a such polynomial: you can choose for $g(x)$ any arbitrary polynomial and the resultant one $$P(x) = (x^4+x^3-3x^2+4x-4)\cdot g(x) + (2x^3-5x^2+7x-3)$$ satisfy in fact the property of your statement.

In particular you can do $P(x)=2x^3-5x^2+7x-3$ so the polynomial is the rest itself in whose case the answer is the constant polynomial $7$.

For this, you have written yourself the general answer, where $g(x)$ is an arbitrary polynomial (if $g$ has $x=2$ as a root then the rest is still $7$ of course).